# What does SET server=%~1 mean in a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Could you please explain what does it mean in bat file:

```
SET server=%~1
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/112135/1056359

Comment: [batch variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428777/whats-the-difference-between-a-and-variable-variables)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does %~d0 mean in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the value of the environment variable `server` to the first command-line argument, with the `"` quotes removed.

Comment: what does SET "$=%~1" means ? @Magoo

Comment: @SubhamTripathi: Please don't use comments to ask questions - post your own question. "$" has no special significance in batch, unlike assembler. It's just another environment variable, so simply substitute `$` for `server` in the above. Personally, I use `$` (or sometimes `@ # _` as a prefix for flags or temporary variables where I have little control over what I'm attempting to flag - filenames or XML tags of significance to the procedure for instance.