# Was unexpected at this time. -- SQL Server exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\prueba_bat.bat'

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a .bat on SQL Server:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\prueba_bat.bat'
```

when I execute the output is:

```
f" >> archivo_union.txt was unexpected at this time. NULL
```

I want to join all the files and make only one and bluk the new file

My .bat code is

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\jlroja01\Documents\Download\Servicio\

for %f in (*) do type "%f" >> new_files_united.txt

pause
exit
```

If I execute it from the cmd prompt, it works.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason why you're using a batch file for this task, when a command is all you need. Were you to use a batch file, you could probably still do that with a single line, `@Type "C:\Users\jlroja01\Documents\Download\Servicio\*">"new_files_united.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is a specific problem of SQL Server.

Try to replace the line

```
for %f in (*) do type "%f" >> new_files_united.txt
```

with

```
for %%f in (*) do type "%%f" >> new_files_united.txt
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428976/2224701).

> If I execute it from the cmd prompt, it works.

When you execute just the line

`for %f in (*) do type "%f" >> new_files_united.txt`

from cmd, it works.
But when you execute the whole bat script, it produces the same error without `exec xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: I made a change in the line command but now I got the next output : 'C:\Users\jlroja01\Documents\prueba_bat.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NULL

Comment: This comment is probably related to @Compo 's suggestion & not to this answer...?